# How do I access the class using "this" inside an each function of the class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have a class and an each method like the following:

```
var dog {
    breed: "huskey",
     
    function printBreed(){
      $("ul li").each(function() {
            $(this).html() = dog.breed;
        });
    }
}
```

I made each of the list item of the page display "huskey". However, inside the each function, I can't use  `$(this).html() = this.breed;`. Because, this will refer to the list item "li" itself. Besides, calling the object by its name. Is there a generic way to refer to the object like "this".

Comment: Strongly related: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](/q/20279484/4642212), but in this case you’d have to know about the arguments that jQuery methods provide — which you can already do, by reading the [documentation](//api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let’s refer to a corrected version of your code:

```js
const dog = { // Use `const` instead of `var`; `=` was missing.
  breed: "Husky", // Spelling.
  printBreed(){ // `function` is invalid here, so use a method instead.
    $("ul li").each(function(){
      $(this).html(dog.breed); // Assignment to a method call is invalid; `html` accepts an argument to set the value.
    })
  }
};
```

The callback function of jQuery’s `each` is called with `this` bound to the currently iterated element. Obviously, `this` cannot refer to both your element and your `dog` object at the same time.

The `each` callback receives two arguments: the current index, and the currently iterated element. In order to ignore the `this` binding from jQuery, simply use an arrow function instead of a `function` function. `this` will then be taken from lexical scope. See [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/4642212) and [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/4642212) for more details.

The working code with jQuery would look like this:

```js
const dog = {
  breed: "Husky",
  printBreed(){
    $("ul li").each((index, element) => $(element).html(dog.breed));
  }
};

dog.printBreed();
```

Note that an `each` loop isn’t necessary in your case. You could’ve simply written the code like so:

```js
const dog = {
  breed: "Husky",
  printBreed(){
    $("ul li").html(this.breed);
  }
};

dog.printBreed();
```

Even better: use `.text` instead of `.html`. Setting HTML for plain text is overkill.

Even if the `breed` was different for each `<li>`, [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) accepts a function callback. But, you know, use arrow functions as appropriate.

---

Of course, [You Don’t Need jQuery](https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery#you-might-dont-need-jquery), so a vanilla version looks like this:

```js
const dog = {
  breed: "Husky",
  printBreed(){
    document.querySelectorAll("ul li").forEach((element) => element.textContent = this.breed);
  }
}

dog.printBreed();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store a reference:

```
var dog {
    breed: "huskey",
     
    function printBreed(){
      var self = this;
      $("ul li").each(function() {
            $(this).html() = self.breed;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been on my mind too, I resolved to doing

```
var dog {
    breed: "huskey",
     
    function printBreed(){
        classThis  = this
      $("ul li").each(function() {
            $(this).html() = classThis.breed;
        });
    }
}
```